# JBox2D Coordinates Don't Match

Tags: java, jbox2d

Working on a Jbox2D program I created 2 objects a rectangle at (0,10) meters and 10 Meters Wide and 1 meter wide, and a Ball at (1,0) that has a radius of 0.5f Meters

```
//in RectangleObject Class
PolygonShape cs = new PolygonShape();
cs.setAsBox(width, height);

//In CircleObject Class
CircleShape cs = new CircleShape();
cs.m_radius = radius;
```

When my program runs the ball moves toward the platform and hits the rectangle like I expected but the numbers I get back are not what I expect

```
BallX[0] : 1
BallY[0] : 7.9964995
RectX[0] : 1
RectY[0] : 10
```

If the X and Y are calculated from the center of the ball then the ball should only be 0.5 away from the box at Y = 9.5. even if it uses the Diameter it should still be at most 1 meter away at Y = 9.

anyone know why its calculating the Y to be 2 meters away when the Radius is only 0.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments for the polygon shape are "half-width" and "half-height".  It's one of the strange carry-overs from box2d (see the manual [here](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html)), and not the most intuitive behavior.  Try:

```
cs.setAsBox(width / 2, height / 2);
```

Comment: They still don't collide visually but reading through the manual I noticed the "Skin" which is why the number isn't EXACTLY correct. from what I can tell the skin is 0.5f around the surface of the shapes and by scaling everything up 64 times is making the small gap between them inflated as well so I just have to accommodate for that visually as everything is colliding correctly now.

Comment: The skin is supposed to be not perceptible if you're using the correct dimensions.  The default skin is 0.01f (or 1cm)

Comment: Since the X and Y coordinates of the Polygon are the center, I should be able to draw the rectangle as drawRect(getX()-(getWidth()/2),getY()-(getHeight()/2),getWidth(), getHeight()); but what i'm getting is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n0vcecuj9ut4mz8/Screenshot%202014-01-15%2002.44.49.png

A small gap in between the Circle and the Rectangles. Also this is scaled x10 instead of converting to Pixel Coordinates, I just use the literal world coordinates and then scale everything up.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening.  What's the size of the gap in world coordinates?

Comment: I wrote the whole thing over from the ground up from what I learned, and the problem? polygonShape.m_radius = 0.5f which was adding a huge border due to the world scale. changing this to 0.01f removed the issue entirely. Thanks for all your help!